# Syntax highlighting for Go's keywords

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

The following Go keywords, as you can see, are not syntax highlighted.

```
chan
defer
fallthrough
func
go
map
range
type
```

Would it be possible to add these to the list of highlighted keywords? Go is far from a toy language and these keywords comprise several of its core features.